# Listview column reordering auto scroll

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, attached-properties

[image]

I want to reorder my columns in UI,as I have lot of columns I want my listview to auto scroll once I take my dragged column to the end of visible scrollview.Is there a way to do it in MVVM?

Answer (score 0):

It is Possible to Automatic scrolling during drag and drop.
Refer this link - [Scrolling While Drag Drop](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/618014/Automatic-Scrolling-During-Drag-operation)